# Ruby Load multiple xml from a directory in a program to parse them

Tags: ruby, rexml

I want to load a set of xml from a directory and use REXML to parse all the xml in a loop.
I cant seem to create File Object after i start reading from a directory

```
      i=1
     filearray=Array.new
        documentarray=Array.new
        directory = 'xml'
        Dir.foreach(directory).each { |file| 
         next if file == '.' or file == '..'
         filearray[i]=File.open(directory +"/"+file)
       i=i+1
```

Please help

Comment: When you say you can't create the `File` objects. What happens? What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Is the closing curly brace "}" missing in the actual code running, or is that just a typo here?

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file, but not reading it.  This is ugly, but will work:

```
require 'find'

files = []
directory = 'xml'

def get_contents(file)
  contents = ""
  contents = File.open(file).readlines
end

Find.find(directory) do |file|
  next if FileTest.directory?(file)
  files << get_contents(file)
end
```

Hope it helps